# How to get a return value from inside a for/if

Tags: c#, return

I've been looking on the internet for some "return [this code to the next bracket outside of this]" but I've been having no luck. Visual Studio says if I put a return inside the "if", it's "fine", but it's not returning a value to the function call, but I can't put the return inside the function call because it says the string doesn't exist.

The purpose of this function is to convert vowels from user-entered input into hyphens/dashes. I am not able to use .Replace (homework assignment). Apologies if this code actually doesn't work or something, I rely on testing it in Visual Studio, so if there are errors, I can't run it, but it looks like it should do what I want from what I've read.

```
public static string ReplaceVowels(string strInput) 
{
    char[] chars = strInput.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++) 
    {
        if (chars[i] == 'a' || chars[i] == 'e' || chars[i] == 'i' || chars[i] == 'o' || chars[i] == 'u' || chars[i] == 'y') 
        {
            chars[i] = '-';
            string strReformed = new string(chars);
        }
    }
    return strReformed;
}
```

Comment: define string strReformed outside the for loop then change it to  strReformed = ... inside the if.

Comment: you are declaring string inside your for look, it is not in scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move `strReformed` to the bottom, outside of the loops (As it only needs to be done once, after all the characters have been changed):

```
public static string ReplaceVowels(string strInput) {
    char[] chars = strInput.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == 'a' || chars[i] == 'e' || chars[i] == 'i' || chars[i] == 'o' || chars[i] == 'u' || chars[i] == 'y') {
            chars[i] = '-';
        }
    }

    string strReformed = new string(chars);

    return strReformed;
}
```

You can see it in action [<kbd>here</kbd>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4nDkCg).

If you're looking to simplify, you can write this using LINQ pretty easily:

```
public static string ReplaceVowels(string strInput) {
    char[] vowels = new []{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

    return string.Concat(
        strInput
            .ToCharArray()
            .Select(chr => vowels.Contains(chr) ? '-' : chr)
    );
}
```

Comment: Ah, dangit. I thought because the return was giving this error, I wouldn't be able to move anything outside of it because it would have been "out of scope" per se. Thanks much!

Comment: Just a little warning - code is case-sensitive - so it won't replace the `A` in `Amen`.

Comment: Yeah, I wish we could use LINQ but I already got talked to for using "outside of class" stuff. I used a .sum command and had to change it to a foreach loop, haha. Great example for other people who might run into this problem though for sure! @RandRandom using .ToLower would solve this correct? (Not quite sure where I'd put that though)

Comment: @SetariM IDK how LINQ isn't taught first. Without it, .NET would be a much darker place.

Comment: @SetariM - I would include the capital letter into the array (or into the if-condition) but it's FrankerZ's answer maybe he can update it with his idea

Comment: Ah, yeah, I just realized I did come across this. I'll just add it in. Thanks!